# Trying to connect to a SOAP / WSDL service using Python (SOAPPy) - getting ERROR

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, soappy

Im trying to connect to a SOAP/WSDL server through my Python script:

```
    # based on the tutorial:
    # http://www.diveintopython.net/soap_web_services/

     import pprint
     from SOAPpy import WSDL

     WSDLFILE = "https://api.comscore.com/KeyMeasures.asmx?WSDL"
     proxy = WSDL.Proxy(WSDLFILE)

    proxy.soapserver.config.dumpSOAPIn=1
    proxy.soapserver.config.dumpSOAPOut=1
```

When I run this script I get the following error:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/XX/PycharmProjects/Test_Proj/Comscore_connector.py", line 9, in <module>
         proxy = WSDL.Proxy(WSDLFILE)
       File "/Users/XXpython_projects/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SOAPpy/WSDL.py", line 85, in __init__
         self.wsdl = reader.loadFromString(str(wsdlsource))
        File "/Users/XX/python_projects/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wstools/WSDLTools.py", line 47, in loadFromString
          return self.loadFromStream(StringIO(data))
        File "/Users/XX/python_projects/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wstools/WSDLTools.py", line 28, in loadFromStream
          document = DOM.loadDocument(stream)
         File "/Users/XX/python_projects/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wstools/Utility.py", line 645, in loadDocument
           return xml.dom.minidom.parse(data)
         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1918, in parse
           return expatbuilder.parse(file)
         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 928, in parse
           result = builder.parseFile(file)
         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 207, in parseFile
           parser.Parse(buffer, 0)
       xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 6

       Process finished with exit code 1
```

Ive looked a the following links for SOAP examples:
http://users.skynet.be/pascalbotte/rcx-ws-doc/python.htm

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502259-calling-a-web-service-using-soappy/

However, there isn't much I could find elsewhere....

Would really appreciate any advice to point me in the right direction.

Comment: When I try to open your wsdl url, i get asked for a login/pass - are you doing this authentication? If you are authenticating have you tried looking at the wsdl file to make sure it is well-formed?

Comment: Im unsure where to embed the login and password credentials. Can you please help?

Comment: No haven't the faintest idea how to do it. Try searching for soappy authentication.